# Java Web Start - jnlp database connection

Tags: java, mysql, java-web-start, jnlp

My JavaWebStart(using Netbeans) application deploys and functions very well on the apache webserver(localhost), BUT when I connect it to its mysql DB, it only deploys but doesnt function. However, it is connecting very well in Netbeans.

I have tried signing in the jar files using 'keytool' but cmd cannot recognize 'keytool' either.
How do I connect this app to its database?

### The JNLP:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://192.168.0.10/JWS2" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>JavaWebStart2</title>
    <vendor>Administrator</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>JavaWebStart2</description>
    <description kind="short">JavaWebStart2</description>
<offline-allowed/>
</information>
<update check="background"/>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+"/>
    <jar href="JavaWebStart2.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="main.NewJFrame">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

### HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</h3>
    <a href="launch.jnlp">Launch the application</a>
    <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton("launch.jnlp")
    </script>
    <!-- Or use the following link element to launch with the application --        
>
    <!--
    
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try to narrow down the problem and post code snippets?  It is difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: highly nebulous even with code though

Comment: 1 possible issue : Make a stand alone app (public static void main ...) Connect to db from threre mightbe the user is local only (mysql) need to make a user that can connect from any host. 2. did u check the security settings? web start allows connections to remote hosts besides parent server by default? else edit security policy

Comment: Managed to sign all my jars, but now am getting a localhost error in the Exception. An unsigned jar:  "http://189.106.14.57/JWS2mystuff/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar". Can anyone tell me how to sign this localhost path-jar?